# jQuery - scroll to <li> with animated height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have confusing problem with scroll to clicked element `<li>`.

When I am clicking on `<li>` element, it has `animate()` method which is change height of element from 270 to 450. After this action it should animate scroll to clicked element. But everything works fine(if I will open and close), but when I open(without closing) first element and click in third, I have wrong offset property because of animation, and scroll is animating to much lower (too much for 180px.)

JS from require

```
wideFolio: function() {
        $( '.fo-content li' ).on( 'click', function(a){
            a.preventDefault();
            var list = $( '.fo-content li' );
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var flag;

            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 180 }, 500);

            if( $( this ).css( "height" ) == "270px" ) {
                list.animate({ height: "270px" }, 500 );
                $(this).animate({ height: "450px" }, 500, );
            }
            else {
                $(this).animate({ height: "270px" }, 500 );
            }



            console.log("#" + id);

        });
    },
```

In HTML is just ul => 4x li.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/husky999/vcmqj3xL/1/

No problem! please focus on first two elements. open first and click into second.

Comment: Would it be ok for you to use CSS only? http://jsfiddle.net/vcmqj3xL/2/

Comment: It would be cool, but we missing animated scroll to clicked element;)

Comment: But ok, now js does not manipulate with animate() on coords, but css do same thing, and scroll againt goes into failed position (offset().top + diference)

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/vcmqj3xL/3/
I gave 'max-height' to '.row', otherwise we wouldn't have any overflow with 'height: auto'. Animate is called after 500ms which is the transition duration for CSS. If you call animate() directly, it would mess up with increasing height (which increases from the top)

Comment: Ohh, nice trick you made here, container height where you added height:) That is what i expect! Thanx:) I will refactor this for page use:) 
Dziękuję/Thanks/Danke:)

Comment: Guys, had done it with jquery animate 'complete' statement. Js will make anmate scroll to point, when incerase height animate is complete. 

https://jsfiddle.net/husky999/vcmqj3xL/5/

GL! Ty